# install4j + allow installer to create multiple new directories for installation location

Tags: install4j

I have issue with Installer generated with install4j. During the "Install files" action it throws error as below [image: Error]

I see these errors in log file:

[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.InstallFilesAction: Before install file: C:\Dir1\Dir2\jre\bin\file.dll; size: 24992 bytes; exists: false
[INFO] fileTime: Mon Mar 28 13:11:06 IST 2016, mode: 644, overwriteMode: Always ask except for update, shared: false, uninstallMode: If created, delayIfNecessary: false
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.InstallFilesAction: Install file not successful: C:\Dir1\Dir2\jre\bin\file.dll.dll
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.InstallFilesAction: Execute action not successful

On debugging it looks like the installer is unable to create the installation location. The user as admin privileges.

In recent observation I found that the above error occurs only when I use a particular word(calling it "home") in the installation location, like c:\Home\dir2. If I choose any other path it installs fine. I do not understand the behaviour. Can anybody help me out with this.

Comment: It's difficult to  understand your question. Please try to analyze your problem more in detail and formulate it in such a way that somebody else can reproduce it.

Comment: Please see new description.

Comment: Sound like a permission issue with the "Home" directory

Comment: "Home" is a new/fresh directory created during this installation. Is there a way to set permission to the installation directory, so as to avoid any other default permission? (Note- This is a windows platform).

Comment: There is the "Add Windows file rights" action to change permissions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the installer can not create the installation directory, right? Do you using the "*Installation location*" action provided by the install4j framework? This action handles the creation of the directory automatically depend on the priviliges the user has. Otherwise you have to ensure the dircetory will be created before the "*Install files*" action will be running.

Comment: Yes, I have been using "Installation Location" action provided by install4j framework. This is happening in only few systems. I checked the user privileges, and the user has admin privileges. I even added the 'require admin user' action to ensure the installer is executed by admin user privilege.

Comment: Also, this is the issue only when default path is selected. If user edits the text box of "Installation location" action, installer is still able to create a new folder and proceed.

Comment: Have added the complete description after some more debugging